# Delete attribute from SQLAlchemy model object

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, orm

I'm trying to delete an attribute from model object that is created on the go, but there seems to be some problem doing so. So, far I've searched through every place including SQLAlchemy documentation and some of its code to find a potential fix but unable to find one.

Below code works fine on python classes but not with a class inherited from `declarative_base`

```
    for row in data:
        model_obj = DBEngine.models.User()
        [setattr(model_obj, key, value) for key, value in row.items()]

        # below line doesn't work as expected, instead of deleting the 
        # attribute it just sets the value of attribute to None
        delattr(model_obj, 'localedit')

        session.add(model_obj)
```

User model

```
Base = declarative_base()

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'user'

    id        = Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True)
    localedit = Column('localedit', String,  default="0000-00-00 00:00:00")
```

I've also tried deleting the attribute using `del` but it's doing the same job as `delattr`, I guess both `del` and `delattr` calling the same code under the hood.

I'm totally stumped on this problem and couldn't come up with anything.
Any help would be appreciated, Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this was expected, as SQLAlchemy ORM mapped objects don't support this particular state for an attribute, that is, attribute doesn't exist and would raise AttributeError. for an ORM mapped class, a mapped attribute always defaults to None and/or empty collection. there's a little bit of an introduction to this here: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/tutorial/orm_data_manipulation.html#instances-of-classes-represent-rows

For this particular problem, you can define your column as

```
localedit = Column('localedit', String,  FetchedValue())
```

FetchedValue is used when the database is configured to provide some automatic default for a column. So, in this case you only want to ignore the column this would work like a charm. Updated model would look something like:

```
Base = declarative_base()

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'user'

    id        = Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True)
    localedit = Column('localedit', String,  FetchedValue())
```